# laravel 5.7 redirect to the same page to an section ID

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel and couldn't find any clue to this issue.

I have a page structured like this

```
<section id="main">
</section>
<section id="about">
</section>
<section id="review">
</section>
<section id="contact">

@inc.messages
<form >
</form>

</section>
```

the page is long, when the validations fails 
the errors are stored in inc.message and are well reported but the
page goes back to the main view "/" but I need it to get back to the section with id "/#contact" as otherwise the customer won't be able to read the errors.

it should be something like this

```
if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return redirect()->route::view("/#contact")->withErrors($v->errors());
    }
```

but I am using view in the wrong way as I can't find a way to route the redirection to "/#contact".

Is it possible to get on the selection or trig a js method within the controller?

ok I solved using the laravel documentations: the method modified is "submit" and those are the modifications:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name'=>'required',
            'phone'=>'required|numeric|digits_between:8,15',
            'email'=>'required|email',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->to('/'.'#contact')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }
```

and I added "use Validator;"

thank you all

Comment: try return redirect(route('nameOfRoute')."/#contact")

Comment: thanks @spartyboy but i get this error message:  public function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
    {
        if (! is_null($route = $this->routes->getByName($name))) {
            return $this->toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute);
        }
 
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");
    }

Comment: please send your web.php file and your controller where you handled the routing

Comment: @spartyboy I modified the post adding what you required, thanks

Comment: correct this to return redirect()->to('/'.'/#contact'); return redirect()->to('/'.'#contact');

Comment: @spartyboy thanks, it doesn't give any error but doesn't behaves as it should it still redirect to the beginning of the page. I use bootstrap but I tried manually to input /#contact and it works as it should. I have to mention that I am using homestead for the development. so i input homestead.test/#contact in the address bar

Comment: @spartyboy thanks all your solutions works now, I changed the method, pls look the main question for explanation

Answer (score 5):

can you try

```php
    return redirect()->to('/link address'.'/#contact')
    or return redirect(route('name').'/#contact')
```

Comment: thank you Neon I got this: "Route [/#contact] not defined." I even tried to add the route in the router but nothing..

Comment: i used this ` return redirect()->to('/test'.'/#contact')` and it worked for me https://snag.gy/xQNp2s.jpg

Comment: could the problem be that I am doing it on the index page so your command looks like this return redirect()->to('/'.'/#contact')`

Comment: ooh you are in the index page, then you should have already have a `Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');` route already defined, then you can use something like this `redirect()->to('/'.'/#contact')`

Comment: thanks all your solutions works now, I changed the method, pls look the main question for explanation