# How to add section ID in Route - Laravel 8

Tags: php, html, database, laravel, forms

I have an HTML section that tagged with ID below:

```
<section id="contactus" style="background-color: #fff">
```

it is a Contact Us From that will send emails to admin but i want the route to go back to this section after submitting the form

this is the Route:

```
Route::get('/', [ContactUsFormController::class, 'createForm']);
Route::post('/', [ContactUsFormController::class, 'ContactUsForm'])->name('contact.store');
```

so '/' is my homepage and the from is there

how to get back to that section with the ID of "contactus" after submitting the form?

Controller:

```
class ContactUsFormController extends Controller {

// Create Contact Form
public function createForm(Request $request) {
  return view('/#contactus');
}

// Store Contact Form data
public function ContactUsForm(Request $request) {

    // Form validation
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'subject'=>'required',
        'message' => 'required'
     ]);

    //  Store data in database
    Contact::create($request->all());

    //  Send mail to admin
    \Mail::send('mail', array(
        'name' => $request->get('name'),
        'email' => $request->get('email'),
        'subject' => $request->get('subject'),
        'user_query' => $request->get('message'),
    ), function($message) use ($request){
        $message->from($request->email);
        $message->to('email@eamil.com', 'Admin')->subject($request->get('subject'));
    });

    return back()->with('success', 'Thank you');
}

}
```

Comment: @EsTeAa i did it, it didn't work

Comment: You can't do it like this. By writing this: ```return view('/#contactus');``` you're telling your app to return the view named ```/#contactus.blade.php``` which probably not exists. You should ```return redirect("http://YOUR_URL.com#contactus")```

Comment: You can try `return redirect()->to('/test'.'/#contact');` according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53888681/15070659

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/', [ContactUsFormController::class, 'createForm'])->name(contact.create);
```

You can specify a name in the route

```
return redirect()->route(contact.create)->with('success', 'Thank you');
```